# How to wire a glow plug?

Tags: wiring, glowplugs

I basically am looking for terminals where I am supposed to connect the required VCC and GND on this [Glow Plug](http://s.aliexpress.com/ZFnqqE7b?)
When I check the continuity using the multimeter,it comes out as a single unit.
Does that mean that the glow plug is dead?

Comment: Dear Mechanics mods, why was this migration allowed?

Comment: @cde I don't think SE's migration mechanism require Mechanics.SE moderators to sanction the migration. Sometimes the EE.SE mods will ask in chat if a question is migration-worthy out of courtesy but that is at their discretion

Comment: @zaid users or a mod on the recipient side can reject the migration with close votes.

Comment: Well, judging by the voting this particular Q&A was well-received. Not sure what you're unhappy about.

Comment: @cde - I'd be very reluctant to close this question (or send it back to electronics). Not our typical question, but it *does* fit the bill of being about a motor driven vehicle. It has been pretty well received. I guess if enough people put on here to close it, I'll go with it, but I'm not going to do it out of hand.

Comment: The question was migrated just in few minutes while I was editting. The basic purpose of this question was to ask how to wire the glow plug to make a hot air soldering gun and safety purpose of doing so. I was just checking if I have posted the link correctly and in mean time it was migrated.

Comment: @zaid I'm unhappy about good electronics questions being migrated out. I'm mainly an electronics site user.

Comment: Understood. Sadly I can't help you there . I haven't had much success in convincing the folks on EE.SE that some of the questions they close as off-topic are indeed within the scope of the site.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk the lesson may be to post the question you mean to the first time, and not plan to only fix it up with edits later.  Had you posted on EESE that you were trying to make a soldering tool from a model engine glowplug, you would have been quickly advised that this is not a sensible way to solder and the question would likely still have been closed.  Instead, you posted what looked like a question about engines, and it got migrated to a site where that question actually posted may or may not be on topic, but seems to have been well received - even if in a way irrelevant to your goal.

Comment: To OP and @cde - Please understand that the mods on EESE are ***very*** quick to migrate *anything* over here which remotely looks like it has something to do with internal combustion engines or automobiles. They don't ask the MVM&R mods if we want it (most of the time) and once we do get it, if we reject the migration, the question is closed on the originating side. In this case, I don't see how it would be fair to the OP. Anyway, in this case, the question was answered very well. That doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: @paulster2 mod. Singular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A glow plug is essentially an intentional short circuit that heats up a wire and ignites whatever fuel is in or connected to the glow plug.

Polarity rarely matters in this. But typically, the construction has the larger body as "ground" and the center pin as "vcc". There is an isolation ring that protects the two from each other, so current goes through the wire.

[image]

Comment: I just added the link to the glow plug. Thank you for the answer. I will try and get back.

Comment: Note that *model* engine glowplugs typically are designed for only around 1.5v, not the 12v proposed in the original question.  They have an expensive platinum element that remains able to initiate combustion of methanol based "glow fuel" from retained heat, needing electric current only during starting (or with 4-cycle models, sometimes at low RPM's)